# Find the Cell Number, free the Mayor

Tags: riddle, mathematics, rhyme, calculation-puzzle, computer-science

Last night, the mayor of a small town was kidnapped. 2000 suspects have been brought into the local prison based off eyewitness reports as to what the suspect looked like.One of these 2000 suspects is the kidnapper .You,the local detective, have to find out the culprit. But this particular criminal is intelligent, leaving no clues or leads whatsoever. However, the culprit does appreciate good intelligence. There is a note on your desk that reads:

"Figure out my riddle, decode my confusing code,
 And then I will lift the town's most burdening load,
 Yes you guessed right, if you figure it out, I think it will be fair,
 to give you my jail cell number, so I can tell you about the Mayor"

**"0 is 1 and 5 is 248,832,**
**root the sum of me and 7 less squared and the answer is bad luck for you"**

### **I am your first two digits**

**"Don't go too fast, that's more bad luck, 
to counteract it, 
  you'll have to use a hex**

**My name is 1011-1010-1101 and that's not all, my purpose is to perplex**

**Tell me my name and my favourite singer, and you'll get out soon**

**If you're able to do all of this and tell me now, I'll gladly fly you to the moon.**

**Count the leters of your answers, and sum it all into one,**

**these are the next two digits of the code,**

**You've won the battle my dear friend , but the war has only begun"**

---

Comment: Will be revealing the answer in an hour. Everyone can have a chance to submit their answer before then, good luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:**

> 1215?

"0 is 1 and 5 is 248,832, root the sum of me and 7 less squared and the answer is bad luck for you"
**I am your first two digits**

> 12: 12<sup>0</sup> =1, 12<sup>5</sup>=248832
>  root the sum of me and 7 less squared: root(x<sup>2</sup>+(x-7)<sup>2</sup>)=13 => root(12<sup>2</sup>+5<sup>2</sup>)=13 => root(169)=13 so x matches 12

"Don't go too fast, that's more bad luck, to counteract it, you'll have to use a hex

My name is 1011-1010-1101 and that's not all, my purpose is to perplex

> BAD - in hexadecimals 1011=B, 1010=A, 1101=D

Tell me my name and my favourite singer, and you'll get out soon
If you're able to do all of this and tell me now, I'll gladly fly you to the moon.

> I'm guessing his singer is Frank Sinatra - "Fly to moon" song

Count the leters of your answers, and sum it all into one,

these are the next two digits of the code,

> 15: "BAD" - 3 letters, "Frank Sinatra" - 12 letters

Comment: You're so close. But the answer is partially wrong

Comment: I don't want to spoil anything, which is why I can't tell you where you went wrong. But just give it more careful consideration.

Comment: well done :) ! You got it

Comment: Yay! The equation could've been done better, but I don't know how to write math friendly text and I've already guessed it was 12, so only needed to verify

Comment: If you're interested, you could try your hand at part 2 -   https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53676/saving-the-mayor-part-2